# How do I display gt tables created in a loop in RMarkdown Word output?

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt

I'm having trouble getting RMakrdown to display `gt` tables in Word output when the tables are created inside a loop.

Straightforward use of `gt` with Word output works as expected:

````
---
title: "Testing gt"
output:
  word_document: default
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
gt::gt(gt::exibble, rowname_col = 'row', groupname_col = 'group')
```
````

When making tables in a loop, `print` must be called, but with HTML output this works fine:

````
---
title: "Testing gt"
output:
  html_document: default
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 1) {
  print(gt::gt(gt::exibble, rowname_col = 'row', groupname_col = 'group'))
}
```
````

But combining these does not work:

````
---
title: "Testing gt"
output:
  word_document: default
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 1) {
  print(gt::gt(gt::exibble, rowname_col = 'row', groupname_col = 'group'))
}
```
````

In the last example, the table contents are present, but the table structure is gone; the document contains one line per cell.

As I was debugging this, I think the need call to `print()` is at the heart of the issue: using `print` in the first example causes it to produce the same output as the third example, but omitting `print` from the third example causes is to produce nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to achieve you desired result would be to first convert the `gt` table to openxml code using `gt::as_word` and second wrap in an `openxml` chunk like so:

````
---
title: "Testing gt"
output:
  word_document: default
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in 1) {
  tab <- gt::gt(gt::exibble, rowname_col = "row", groupname_col = "group") |> gt::as_word()
  cat("```{=openxml}", tab, "```", sep = "\n")
}
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works! I punched it up a bit so that I can still knit to other formats or "run chunks" in an interactive session, and it's too long to include as a comment. But this definitely answered my question and I'm grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Riffing off of @stefan's answer, here's a solution that works with other output formats and in interactive sessions:

````
---
title: "Testing gt"
output:
  word_document: default
---

```{r hack-gt-print, include=FALSE}
# New method for printing gt_tbl objects
print.gt_tbl <- function(x, ...) {
  if (isTRUE(knitr::opts_knit$get('rmarkdown.pandoc.to') == "docx")) {
    cat("```{=openxml}", gt::as_word(x), "```\n\n", sep = "\n")
  } else {
    gt:::print.gt_tbl(x, ...)
  }
}

# register the method
registerS3method("print", "gt_tbl", print.gt_tbl)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis', message=FALSE}
# message=FALSE suppresses the message about our new S3 method overwriting gt's
for (i in 1:2) {
  tab <- gt::gt(gt::exibble, rowname_col = "row", groupname_col = "group")
  print(tab)
}
```
````

I also (finally) poked around `gt`'s source code, and it looks like they're working on a `gt_group` object that's meant to simplify the printing of a list of tables. As far as I can tell that's not on CRAN yet, so this will do for now (but hopefully won't be necessary for my next project).