# Formating problem when trying to export table result to pdf via qmd

Tags: r, markdown, quarto, gt

I use the following code to create tables for likert scales

```
``{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
data_split <- split(data, data$class)

for(i in seq_along(data_split))
{
  tab <- data_split[[i]] %>%
      pivot_longer(11:48, names_to = "Item") |>
      tabyl(Item, value, show_na=F, sort=T) |>
      adorn_percentages("row") %>% 
      adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 0) %>% 
      adorn_ns(position="front") %>%
      gt() |>
      opt_stylize(style = 1) |>
  print(tab)
}
```

This works fine when exporting it to html, unfortunately when choosing pdf, the result are shown without format and not as table, just the raw results/texts.

Any ideas?

Here the qhole markdown:

```
---
title: "Results"
author: ""
header-includes:
  \usepackage[ dvipsnames ]{ xcolor }
format: 
  pdf:
    classoption: landscape
    geometry:
      - top=20mm
      - left=15mm
editor: visual
---

{r setup, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)

library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(janitor)
library(gt)


data <- read.csv("C:/Users/.../dataset.csv", quote = "'\"", na.strings=c("", "\"\""), stringsAsFactors=FALSE, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")

# LimeSurvey Field type: F
data[, 1] <- as.numeric(data[, 1])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[1] <- "I like swimming."
data[, 1] <- factor(data[, 1], levels=c(3,2,1,0),labels=c("++", "+", "-", "--"))
names(data)[1] <- "I like swimming."
# LimeSurvey Field type: F
data[, 2] <- as.numeric(data[, 2])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[2] <- "Reading is useful."
data[, 2] <- factor(data[, 2], levels=c(3,2,1,0),labels=c("++", "+", "-", "--"))
names(data)[2] <- "Reading is useful."
# LimeSurvey Field type: F
data[, 3] <- as.numeric(data[, 3])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[3] <- "My teacher is friendly."
data[, 3] <- factor(data[, 13], levels=c(3,2,1,0),labels=c("++", "+", "-", "--"))
names(data)[3] <- "My teacher is friendly."
# LimeSurvey Field type: F
data[, 4] <- as.numeric(data[, 4])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[4] <- "Test ABC"
data[, 4] <- factor(data[, 4], levels=c(3,2,1,0),labels=c("++", "+", "-", "--"))
names(data)[4] <- "Test ABC"

# LimeSurvey Field type: F
data[, 5] <- as.numeric(data[, 5])
attributes(data)$variable.labels[5] <- "class"
data[, 5] <- factor(data[, 5], levels=c(1,2,3,4),labels=c("1.", "2.", "3.", "4."))
names(data)[5] <- "class"


Rücklauf (vollständig ausgefüllt): r casesFinished Personen

\newpage

Anhang

Gesamtergebnisse

{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}


data_selected %>%
    pivot_longer(1:4,
               names_to = "Item") |>
    tabyl(Item, value, show_na=F, sort=T) |>
    adorn_percentages("row") %>% 
    adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 0) %>% 
    adorn_ns(position="front") %>% 
    gt() |>
    opt_stylize(style = 1)

\newpage

Ergebnisse nach Klassenstufe

{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}

data_split <- split(data, data_selected$class)


for(i in seq_along(data_split))
{
  tab <- data_split[[i]] %>%
      pivot_longer(1:4, names_to = "Item") |>
      tabyl(Item, value, show_na=F, sort=T) |>
      adorn_percentages("row") %>% 
      adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 0) %>% 
      adorn_ns(position="front") %>%
      gt() |>
      opt_stylize(style = 1) |>
      tab_header(title = md("Results for class"), subtitle = names(data_split[i])) |>
  print(tab)
}
```

Example for Dataset (data.csv):

```
" [(1) I like swimming.],"" [(2) Reading is useful.]"","" [(3) My teacher is friendly.]"","" [(4) Test ABC]"",""class"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""2"",""1"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""2"",""1"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
","""","""","""","""""
"2,""3"",""2"",""3"",""1"""
"3,""2"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"2,""3"",""2"",""3"",""1"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""2"",""1"""
"3,""2"",""2"",""3"",""2"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""2"""
"2,""2"",""2"",""2"",""2"""
"3,""2"",""2"",""1"",""2"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""0"",""2"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""2"""
"1,""1"",""2"",""2"",""2"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""2"",""2"""
"2,""2"",""3"",""3"",""2"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""2"",""2"""
"2,""2"",""3"",""2"",""2"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"3,""2"",""3"",""3"","""""
"3,""3"",""2"",""1"",""1"""
"3,""2"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""2"",""1"""
"2,""2"",""3"",""2"",""2"""
"2,""2"",""3"",""3"",""2"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""2"",""3"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"2,""2"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"3,""2"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"2,""3"",""2"",""3"",""3"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""2"",""3"""
"2,""2"",""3"","""",""3"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""2"",""3"""
"3,""2"",""3"",""2"","""""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"2,""2"",""3"",""2"",""2"""
"1,""2"",""2"",""2"",""2"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"0,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""1"",""2"""
"0,""1"",""2"",""1"",""2"""
"2,""1"",""3"",""3"",""2"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""2"",""2"""
"2,""2"",""2"",""2"",""2"""
"2,""2"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"3,""3"",""2"",""3"",""3"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""2"",""3"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""2"",""3"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"2,""2"",""3"",""3"","""""
"3,""3"",""3"",""2"",""3"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""3"""
","""","""","""","""""
"2,""3"",""1"",""3"",""4"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""4"""
"3,""2"",""3"",""2"",""4"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""4"""
"2,""2"",""3"",""2"",""4"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""4"""
"2,""2"",""2"",""2"",""4"""
"3,""1"",""3"",""1"",""4"""
"0,""1"",""0"",""2"",""4"""
"1,""3"",""2"",""2"",""4"""
"3,""2"",""3"",""3"",""4"""
"2,""3"",""2"",""3"",""4"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""2"",""4"""
"2,""2"",""3"",""2"",""4"""
"2,""3"",""2"",""2"",""4"""
"2,""2"",""3"",""2"",""4"""
"2,""2"",""3"",""2"",""4"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""4"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""4"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""2"",""4"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""2"",""4"""
"3,""2"",""2"",""1"",""4"""
"2,""3"",""2"",""2"",""4"""
","""","""","""",""1"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""2"",""1"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"","""""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"3,"""",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"3,""1"",""2"",""3"",""1"""
"2,""3"",""2"",""2"",""1"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""2"","""""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"","""""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"2,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"2,""3"",""2"",""3"",""1"""
","""","""","""","""""
","""","""","""","""""
"3,""3"",""3"",""3"",""1"""
"3,""2"",""3"",""2"",""1"""
"2,""2"",""2"",""2"",""1"""
```

Does that help to reproduce?
Kind regards :-)

Comment: can you share some example code and some mwe qmd example?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [How do I display gt tables created in a loop in RMarkdown Word output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75890958/how-do-i-display-gt-tables-created-in-a-loop-in-rmarkdown-word-output/75891549#75891549) which deals with the case of word output, one possible option would be to output your gt table using `as_latex()` and to wrap the output in a latex code chunk.

Using a minimal reprex using `ggplot2::mpg` as example data:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
keep-md: true
editor: visual
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
library(gt)
```

```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
data_split <- split(mpg, ~class)

for(i in seq_along(data_split))
{
  tab <- data_split[[i]] %>%
      select(-where(is.character)) |>
      pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Item") |>
      tabyl(Item, value, show_na=F, sort=T) |>
      adorn_percentages("row") %>%
      adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 0) %>%
      adorn_ns(position="front") %>%
      gt() |>
      opt_stylize(style = 1) |>
      as_latex()

  cat("```{=latex}", tab, "```", sep = "\n")
}
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thats gorgeous - it worked!